# Why can I not ping a website with over a certain amount of bytes per packet?

Tags: ping

I was wondering what is the max amount of bytes per packet does google.com accept, I tested it out with CMD and turns out that it is 1472.

Why can I not ping with more bytes per packet? Is this value (1472) random or does it mean anything?

Answer (score 2):

You seeing that fact that the IP header is 20 bytes and the ICMP header is 8 bytes.  Those added to 1472 gets you to 1500,  a typical max packet size.  If you go over that its likely the packet is either dropped or fragmented.  either of those will likely result in no response.